# Could not load source './csu/../csu/libc-start.c': 'SourceRequest' not supported

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

```
Could not load source './csu/../csu/libc-start.c': 'SourceRequest' not supported..
```

Here's my basic c code. I'm trying to set a breakpoint on `_start`. And see step by step where it goes on inside the `_start` func. But it shows that error message. There's no `launch.json` file in the directory. How can I get rid of this error on my pc?
I'm using a amd x64 machine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by pasting the csu directory of glibc into the same directory as the c file I was running and debugging. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell GDB where to find files as follows:

```
(gdb) directory /path/to/src
```

You can probably add this command to the [vscode `setupCommands` configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_setupcommands).

Answer (score 0):

As ams said, You can tell GDB where to find files as follows:

(gdb) directory /path/to/src

or simply add:
"miDebuggerArgs": "-d /path/to/src/",

to launch.json so you don't need to type in gdb every time you start debugger